# Alternative to Fuse JS (FuzzySearch Javascript)

Tags: javascript, search, indexing, fuzzy-search

i have **33k+ Records** of Product in Indexed DB. i have implemented search for that using [Fuse js](https://www.fusejs.io/). But For my some cases it wouldn't give proper results. i played with its options but not got satisfied results. So looking for alternative minimal size & wide in functionality of fuzzy search.

Please let me know if you have used or know any js that can give results in most of complex searchs. i am trying to make similar version of [DoFinder](https://www.doofinder.com)